# So I'm trying to use Math.cbrt and my code isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, math

I'm using Math.cbrt and I'm not 100% if this is a thing but Math.sqrt to try to get the The square root and cube roots of every number to 100, my code will be down below. Expected output is what is supposed to be output when every number has been calculated.

```js
let number = 1;
let cube = Math.cbrt(number);
let square = Math.sqrt(number);
if(number = 100){
  console.log("Roots completed your number has been delivered.");
}else{
  console.log(cube);
  console.log(square);
  number += 1;
};
```

Comment: At first, the code is executed only once, secondly, `=` is an assignment operator, the condition is always passed.

Comment: It should be `if (number === 100)`

Comment: @Teemu, not with a falsy assignment.

Comment: @NinaScholz Emphasis on the definite article "the" = ).

Comment: Ok thankyou! I dont really know what the difference from using number + 1 or number += 1 could you please explain?

Comment: `number + 1` does nothing, it just evaluates, and the value is thrown away. `number += 1` is a shorthand of `number = number + 1`, which adds `1` to the value of `number`. What you need in your code is a loop. You've to wrap all the code in a loop (excluding the first line), in order to get it to log all the cubes and squares.

Comment: @Teemu I now understand what your saying im pretty new to JS, how would I go about executing it multiple times to complete the code?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting a value of `number` in the if statement. You are not comparing values.

To compare two values, use this operator: `==`.

i.e.:

```js
let number = 1;
let cube = Math.cbrt(number);
let square = Math.sqrt(number);
if(number == 100){
  console.log("Roots completed your number has been delivered.");
}else{
  console.log(cube);
  console.log(square);
  number += 1;
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much i didnt realize that i was setting number to 100 and not comparing it.